# Every time I run Azureus it wants to restart because of an upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I am using Fedora 16. Every time I run Azureus, it says that it just completed an important update and needs to restart. How can I fix this? Obviously restarting it is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

There could probably be numerous reasons for this to happen. My first *guess* would be wrong permissions on config directories, i.e. something like `~/.azureus` owned by root, such that an update initiated with a non-root user account cannot succeed.

But have a look at [the VuzeWiki page on "Failed Updates"](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Failed_Update#Linux.2FUnix_notes), the procedure explained there could help you.

*Maybe* you get some diagnostic output when you lauch it from a terminal, possibly with a debug/verbosity flag [**1**] (try adding `--help` for further information).  This is all rather general advice, I have no clue about Azureus, sorry.

[**1**] From [another Wiki site](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Commandline_options):

> `-Dazureus.log.stdout=1` Send all log output to standard out / console / terminal.

Maybe this is informative.